# UnknownHostException when trying to connect to a AWS Gateway Private API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, dns, api-gateway, vpc

I followed this:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/ tutorials

to a tee to create a private link between my REST API endpoint.

Essentially, steps that I have done:

- Converted a (previously working) Edge API to a private API (via the AWS API Gateway Console)
- Created a VPC with 2 public subnets and 2 private subnets using this template: https://s3.amazonaws.com/computeblog-us-east-1/apigateway-private-endpoints/BaseVPC.template
- Confirmed that DNS naming and DNS resolution are enabled on the VPC.
- Created a VPC endpoint that attached to the VPC created above. Private DNS is enabled.
- Added this resource policy to the API, then redeployed it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:{aws-account-id}:{rest-api-id}/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-{endpoint}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:{aws-account-id}:{rest-api-id}/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I then used a Java Client created by the AWS SDK: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/ to invoke the API, and got hit with this error:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: {rest-api-id}.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

...

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: {rest-api-id}.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Same issue happened when I used Postman.

As indicated in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html as well as API Gateway console, if I have private DNS enabled, I should be able to invoke the API using the url.

Do I misunderstand something? What is the correct way to be able to successfully invoke the API?

Comment: Can you show how you invoke api?

Comment: Where are you running your Java client/postman, If you are running from your local machine, do you have private connectivity enabled? you are just showing {rest-api-id} in logs as an example correct actual log has abcsomething.execute-api.us-west-2.. , correct?

Comment: IF this is private API, it must be called from within the VPC, e.g. on ec2 instance. Can you confirm and show how are you trying to invoke the API?

Comment: @Marcin you're right, I believe it may be the problem, as I'm not connected to any EC2 instance right now. With the current setup following the tutorials, how do I determine which E2 instance to connect to?

More details I go to the EC2 page on the same AWS account with the VPC and VPCE, and the current number of instances running is 0. There's only a security group: `EndpointSG sg-{number}`, is that the correct one to connect to?

Comment: Start with basic t2.micro and just test with `curl` if you can indeed invoke your api correctly. Then you can take it from there how to use postman (e.g. ssh tunnel).

Answer (score 0):

The resource policy should have the condition based on VPC Endpoint and not on VPC as showed. Try replacing "aws:sourceVpc": "vpce-{endpoint}" by "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-{endpoint}" and then deploy again.

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo. The resource policy is indeed under: `"aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-{endpoint}"`, and the problem still exists.